# Code for Loading One of Two HTML Pages into a Third HTML Page According to the Time of Day

Tags: php, html

I have searched the web for an answer to my question, but with limited success. I am a real newbie when it comes to programming languages. Here's my question: I have one HTML page designed with a "daytime" theme and another with a "nighttime" theme. Then I have a third HTML page where I want to load one of these two WHOLE pages into this third page (not into a div or iframe in the third page), according to the time of day. I want to load the "daytime" theme page during the morning and afternoon hours, and the "nighttime" theme page during the evening/nighttime hours.

I have the following PHP code, but it is not working for me:

```
<?php  
$time = date('G');  
if($time >=0 || $time < 6)  
  {  
  $page = 'indexnight.html';  
  }
if($time >=6 || $time < 18)  
  {  
  $page = 'indexday.html';  
  }  
if($time >=18 || $time < 24)  
  {  
  $page = 'indexnight.html';  
  }  
include ('$page');
?>
```

Can someone check over this and locate any problems with this coding? Also, I need to know where this code should be placed in my third HTML page and if there is any additional coding that needs to go within the body tags of the page.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Date function is not reliable, as it depends on the systems time-setting. If you want accurate data, you have to set the timing using `date_default_timezone_set()` read http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php for more info

Comment: This seems a flawed approach (time of day is different depending where on the planet you are, so this should be determined client-side). Plus you can't really place PHP code in a HTML page (unless you force your server to parse HTML as PHP), so this might be your problem right there.

Answer (score 0):

hey you used single Quote `include ('$page');`  Instead use `include ("$page");`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you control the themes by CSS (which is designed for appearance) rather than HTML (which is designed for content)?  But ignoring that, you should do something like:

```
if ($time >=6 and $time < 18) { readfile('indexday.html');}
else { readfile('indexnight.html');}
```

And that should replace pretty much all your code (except for the $time definition).